# R shinydashboard: capture click event on dashboard body

Tags: javascript, r, shinydashboard, shinyjs

How can I capture click events on the shinydashboard body?

Attempt is below.  It loads a dashboard and gives an alert without clicking on the body.  Then clicking on the body does nothing.  The expected behaviour is that it would alert each time I click on the body.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs())
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  shinyjs::runjs("document.body.addEventListener('click', alert('hello'));")  

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

One idea is to give the body an id and use that with shinyjs::onclick, however I'm not sure how to give the body an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event listener should be a function, not an expression. For example

```
  shinyjs::runjs("document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {alert('hello')});")  

}
```

That way each time a click happens, that function will get called.